# Why is my if statement throwing TypeError: 'int' object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

In the research I've been doing, I've seen a lot of cases where the same word is used as a variable name and a function name or something like that, and as far as I can tell I don't have any of that. But I have the following code:

```
    operators = "['^', '*', '/', '+', '-']"

    def shuntParse(infix):
        print("shunting")
        output = ""
        operatorStack = Stack()

        for token in infix:
            print(token)
            try:
                float(token)
                output + ' ' + token
            except ValueError:
                if ((token in operators) and (operatorStack.capacity() > 0)):
                    while((operators.index(operatorStack.top()) > operators.index(token)) or (operators.index(operatorStack.top()) == operators.index(token))):
                        output + ' ' + operatorStack.pop()
                    operatorStack.push(token)
                elif ((token == '(') or (token in operators)):
                    operatorStack.push(token)
                elif (token == ')'):
                    while (operatorStack.top() != '('):
                        # If stack runs out without finding a left paren, parentheses are not matched
                        output + ' ' + operatorStack.pop()
                    operatorStack.pop()
                else:
                    pass

        while (operatorStack.capacity() != 0):
            output + ' ' + operatorStack.pop()

        return output
```

And when it runs, the following error is thrown:

```
if ((token in operators) and (operatorStack.capacity() > 0)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm really stuck on why this is coming up, and would love some help. Thank you!

Edit: Here is the code used for the operatorStack

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.capacity = 0 

    def push(self, data):
        if (self.head == None):
            self.head = Node(data)                                                                                                                                                                          
            capacity += 1
        else:
            newNode = Node(data)
            newNode.nextNode(self.head)
            self.head = newNode
            capacity += 1

    def pop(self):
        if (self.head == None):
            pass
        else:
            newHead = self.head.nextNode
            oldData = self.head.data
            del self.head
            self.head = newHead
            capacity -= 1
            return oldData
    def top(self):
        return self.head.data
    def capacity(self):
        return self.capacity
```

Comment: Is `operatorStack.capacity` (without the parentheses) an int?

Comment: I do not see it yet, but you very likely named a variable as a function.

Comment: busybear may be right, when the Stack implementation implements capacity as property and not as method it needs to be called without the parentheses.

Comment: Aiyion.Prime so it looks like my mistake was using the same name for the variable (capacity) and the function to return said variable. I didn't think to look at the stack class until busybear asked about it.